# How to map UV on generated Mesh from Curve?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv

Hi I created a Mesh from a curve with a Bevel Object and now I need to UV map it.

It should become a rebar and needs the typical ripples at its sides as displacement. I created a seam and tried different unwrap methods. Actually I hoped that the generated texture coordinates would fit already but it is always stretched along the long part as shown in the picture.

How can I map it as an even cylinder along the mesh so that I can achieve the typical rebar look?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the UV map to be flat and straight, as if the rebar was still straight.
The rings will then just follow the bent shape.

[image]

**UV Map**
The UV Map is the most important thing here. It needs to be flat and straight.
Don't forget to cut off the end caps with seams, like I did.

I used the default *Angle Based* unwrap, which may/may not work in your case.
There's also an addon called *UV Squares* which comes with Blender and will do the work for you.

[image]

**Mapping Node**
The Mapping node will allow you to precisely scale the texture.
Notice that in my case, the Y Scale is considerably smaller.
Also, don't forget to plug in the *UV Map output*.

[image]

**Note**
I used a generated wave texture for the rings. With a proper image texture you'll surely get better results.

Good luck.

Comment: Many thanks, I forgot to mark the seams at the caps and to scale.

Answer (score 0):

If you check 'Use UV for Mapping' in a curve's Data tab > Texture Space panel, it doesn't need manual unwrapping. When converted to a mesh (if that's necessary,) the curve's length and circumference, (its geometric U and V)  will be mapped to 0-1 in the texture UV of an automatically generated map.

Comment: Thank you I tried that but it still gives me some distortion. But I guess it is because I  started with a vertex, extruded and beveled it and converted the result back to a curve, because it was easier to create the shape with. Will try it with a curve from the beginning now.