# Node Coil texture

Tags: node-editor, screw-modifier

I'm trying to create a node texture combination in order to reproduce or better said give the illusion of an object wrapped around another object like a coil. Just like the bricks texture but going around like a coil. I'm doing this to eliminate the multitude of polygons created by doing it with the screw modifier. Something like in the picture attached. Thank you.[image]

Comment: Hello :). Just yesterday there was a [very similar problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161957/78972). I'm sure you'll find what you need there.

Comment: Yes, good catch. Thank you